# flash socket policy

Tags: flash

Using flash sockets in my irc client, can I serve the socket policy file somehow other than thru socket policy file server (without server)? If I use the Security.loadPolicyFile function, i do not need any daemon, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I know from using TCP/IP Sockets and XML. I've set up a Ruby server with a Flash client successfully, but want to know more about chat servers. I hope some of this is helpful.

**You need a Daemon with Flash AS3. Here's the documentation.** 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000318.html

[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/daemonLil.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/daemonLil.jpg)

To create a socket connection, you must create a server-side application to wait for the socket connection request and send a response to the SWF file. This type of server-side application can be written in a programming language such as Java, Python, or Perl. To use the XMLSocket class, the server computer must run a **daemon** that understands the protocol used by the XMLSocket class. The protocol is described in the following list:

• XML messages are sent over a full-duplex TCP/IP stream socket connection.
• Each XML message is a complete XML document, terminated by a zero (0) byte.
• An unlimited number of XML messages can be sent and received over a single XMLSocket connection.

**Understanding the security changes in Flash Player 10**
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_security_changes_02.html

---

**XML SECURITY POLICY**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

**FLASH CLIENT**
Remember to set Publish Settings to Access Network Only.

**SERVER**
Open a separate port for security policy, and keep it running in the background.